# How to flash all the properties of an object in Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, flash-message

I'm using Express with connect-flash.

In validating a form, I am currently using this and it works:

```
req.flash('old_name', object.name)
req.flash('old_email', object.email)
req.flash('old_age', object.age)
```

How can I iterate through the properties of the object and flash for each? I'd like to be able to reuse the solution to validate other objects.

Something like:

```
for (let property in object) {
    req.flash('old_' + property, object[property])
}
```

`console.log(object)`:

```
{
    _id: 'sjdfoiasdhfaushdfhweuhu',
    name: 'Harry',
    email: 'harry@example.com',
    age: 45
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with the `for..in` solution you have proposed yourself? It seems to do what you're asking for.

Comment: TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON

Comment: Are all your properties simple types or are some of them arrays or objects?  If they are arrays or objects, what do you want to happen in that case?  If those objects have embedded objects, what do you expect to happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out. I think this solution will be pretty specific to Express.js with mongoose:

```
for (var prop in object._doc) {
    if (object._doc.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
        req.flash('old_' + prop, object._doc[prop])
    }
}
```